# How to clear listview my data

Tags: java, android

I cannot clear my data on aplication. If i selected name of my teacher, will showing schedule learning from my teacher. But after i selected another name teacher, data schedule from first teacher cannot clear and still seen on data schedule last teacher.

This is my script
JadwalDosen.java

```js
package www.kates.com;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class JadwalDosen extends ListActivity{
 private JadwalDosenAdapter adapter;
 private Spinner dosen;
 private List<String> iddosen = new ArrayList<String>();
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
  super.onCreate(bundle);
  setContentView(R.layout.jadwaldosen);
  adapter = new JadwalDosenAdapter(this, getListView().getId());
  setListAdapter(adapter);
  dosen = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.jadwalnamadosen);
  Connector con = new Connector("get_dosen.php","GET",null) {
   @Override
   public void onFinish(JSONArray data) {
    if(data!=null){
     if(data.length()>0){
      List<String> namaDosen = new ArrayList<String>();
      for(int i=0;i<data.length();i++){
       try {
        iddosen.add(data.getJSONObject(i).getString("IdDosen"));
        namaDosen.add(data.getJSONObject(i).getString("NamaDosen"));
       } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
      }
      ArrayAdapter<String> sAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(JadwalDosen.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,namaDosen);
      sAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
      dosen.setAdapter(sAdapter);
      dosen.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
       public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        List<NameValuePair> info = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        info.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_dosen", iddosen.get(pos)));
        Connector con = new Connector("get_jadwal_dosen.php","GET",info) {
         @Override
         public void onFinish(JSONArray data) {
          if(data!=null){
           if(data.length()>0){
            for(int j=0; j<data.length();j++){
             try {
              adapter.add(data.getJSONObject(j));
              adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
             } catch (JSONException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
             }
            }
           }
          }
         }
        };
       }

       public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        
       }
      });
     }
    }
   }
  };
 }
}
```

JadwalDosenAdapter.java

```js
package www.kates.com;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JadwalDosenAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<JSONObject>{

 public JadwalDosenAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
  super(context, resource);
 }
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final JSONObject item = getItem(position);
        if (!item.equals(null)) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.jadwal_dosen_item, parent, false);
            try {
                ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.jadwal_makul)).setText(item.getString("NamaMakul"));
                ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.jadwal_kategori)).setText(item.getString("KategoriJadwal"));
                ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.jadwal_hari)).setText(item.getString("Hari"));
                ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.jadwal_jam)).setText("Jam ke- : " + item.getString("JamMulai") + " s/d " + item.getString("JamSelesai"));
                ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.jadwal_kelas)).setText(item.getString("NamaKelas"));
                ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.jadwal_ruang)).setText("Ruangan : " + item.getString("Ruang"));
            } catch (Exception exc) {
             exc.printStackTrace();
            }
            return view;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } 
}
```

Please help me

Comment: There's a `clear` method on ArrayAdapters

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you select one teavher you have to update the ids also.So add the line

`iddosen = new ArrayList<String>();` 
Above this line

```
`List<String> namaDosen = new ArrayList<String>();`
```

Answer (score 0):

In youe JadwalDosen.java file make this following change

```
info.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_dosen", iddosen.get(pos)));
                                Connector con = new Connector("get_jadwal_dosen.php","GET",info) {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFinish(JSONArray data) {
                                        if(data!=null){
                                            if(data.length()>0){

                                                for(int j=0; j<data.length();j++){
                                                    try {
                                                        adapter.add(data.getJSONObject(j));
                                                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                };
```

This change will clear your adapter before adding new values to it, so already present values for prev selected coach will get removed and you will only see new values.

Change in JadwalDosenAdapter.java

> Please try to reuse already created view so will reduce the efforts of
>   application to draw new element for each item and will give you better
>   performance of list view as well.

Hope this will solve your problem...

Comment: @adhearie Please accept the answer if it solves your prob.